# C# : Workbook's Close methods doesn't work for Workbook opened on OneDrive

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto, excel-addins

I'm developing a VSTO add-in that calls Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Close method on the current Workbook to allow writing on that file by another process.

If the file is stored locally, the method effectively closes the workbook and frees the handle from the EXCEL.EXE locking the file.

However, when the file is saved on OneDrive, the Close method seems to have no effect. Is that a bug? Any idea?

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
}
        
void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
     Wb.Close(); // doesn't work for oneDrive files ?!
}
```

Comment: If you wait/sleep 10 seconds after `Close`, does that change anything? I've noticed just as a user, that the OneDrive sync seems to take extra time...

Comment: I tried to wait 10s before and after close with Thread.Sleep(10000), but there is no result. The handle persists, and the workbook doesn't close. The file is still held by EXCEL.EXE

Comment: Yeah, you might need to set a timer or sleep in a separate thread so the active thread can pump window messages and everything can shut down eventually. SysInternals used to have a utility called "handle.exe" (or maybe Win SDK?) that can give open handles? If you just call `Close()` and then wait, does handle eventually close??? Calling sleep on active thread might not give the process time to shut things down because the sleep on active thread halts everything. Just ideas...

Comment: Good ideas actually! I used handle.exe to verify what blocks closing. It really was Excel itself. So using a new thread was part of the solution. It seemed Thread.Sleep is not needed, or it may be the handle lives in such a brief period of time in the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the delay, try to run the garbage collector to swipe the heap and release unused COM references that are left intact after closing the workbook. Note, you need to call the GC twice:

```
GC.Collect
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers
GC.Collect
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers
```

Read more about that in the [When to release COM objects in Office add-ins developed in .NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/) article.

Also you may find the [Why doesn’t Excel quit?](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/why-doesnt-excel-quit/) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That + Joseph's idea solved the problem. I'll post the code to answer the question. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph (Thread + Timing idea)'s answer and @Eugene's (CG idea) answer allowed me to find the solution! Here's the code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
}
        
void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
     // Wb.Close(); // DOESN'T WORK
     Thread t = new Thread(() => this.ReleaseWorkbook(ref Wb)); // ReleaseWorkook doesn't work in the current thread
     t.Start();
}

void ReleaseWorkbook(ref Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    Wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 
    Wb = null; 
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling the GC code, you might be able to get away with: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Wb);` However, that might not work when called from a separate thread. IOW, you might be able to get `Wb.Close(); System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Wb)` to work.